Input と If を使ったとき、Input の内容が数字型以外のときのIf 文の対処方法
Python についての質問です。
このコードの使用者がn のinput に文字型やその他の特殊な型を入力したときに、その後にくるif n==str: はエラーを起こさずに潜り抜けられますが、さらにこの後来る、n が2 未満かを判定するときに n が数字型以外だと
'<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'というエラーが起きてしまうのですが、これを対処したくプログラムを色々変えてみましたがうまくいきませんでした。
私としては、これを本当にエラーで返すのではなく、例外処理として無視してほしいのです。
もし、有識者の中にお時間がある方がございましたが、こちらの対処方法について知恵や情報をお借りしたく存じます。
恐れ入りますが、「例外処理を使用者が入力しなければよい」や、「そんな無駄なことをする必要はない」等の、本来私が要求している回答を遥かに外れた回答はお控えください。
k=1
while k==1:
    happen=0
    i=2
    n=int,str(input("素数かどうか知りたい数を入力してください。\n知りたい数＞＞"))
    if n==str:
      print("それは数字ではありません。")
    elif n<2:                           #n が整数型以外のとき、ここでエラーが起きてしまう。
      print(n,"は素数ではありません。")
    elif n>=2:
      if n%2==0 or n%3==0 or n%5==0 or n%7==0:
        print(n,"は素数ではありません。")
      else:
        while i<n**0.5:
          total=n%i
          i=i+1
          if total==0:
              happen=happen+1
        if happen>0:
          print(n,"は素数ではありません。")
        elif happen==0:
          print(n,"は素数です。")
    k=int,str(input("続けて素数を探しますか。Yes=1,No=0\nY/N>>"))
    if k==0:
      break
    elif k==str:
      k=1
    else:
      k=1
print()


色々と突っ込みどころが満載ですが、対処が如何とか以前に、まずn=int,str(input("素数かどうか知りたい数を入力してください。\n知りたい数＞＞"))という文が間違っています。
Python仕様のinput(prompt)の説明にはこの関数は入力から 1 行を読み込み、文字列に変換して (末尾の改行を除いて) 返します。と書かれており、通知されるのは必ず文字列です。
なのでinput('...')を更にstr()で文字列に変換するのは冗長で無駄な処理ですね。
そしてn=int,str(input(...と書かれているのは、おそらく入力された文字列をintに変換しようと考えたのでしょうが、それではコーディングミスですね、intとstr(冗長ですが)の間は,ではなくint関数呼び出しとしての(にして、行末に)を加える必要があります。
ちなみに元の文だとnという変数に入っているデータはエラーメッセージにあるように'tuple'であり、'int'ではありません。
状況を把握するために、この文を実行して何かの結果がnに代入された後、if n==str:が実行される前の場所に、以下3行を挿入して実行してみてください。
print(n)
print(n[0])
print(n[1])

元の前後一行を含めて表示すると以下のようになるでしょう。
    n=int,str(input("素数かどうか知りたい数を入力してください。\n知りたい数＞＞"))
    print(n)
    print(n[0])
    print(n[1])
    if n==str:

そして実行した時に例えば数字の6を入力した場合は以下のように表示されるはずです。
素数かどうか知りたい数を入力してください。
知りたい数＞＞6
(<class 'int'>, '6')
<class 'int'>
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file", line 11, in <module>
    elif n<2:                           #n が整数型以外のとき、ここでエラーが起きてしまう。
         ^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

nが'tuple'であり'int'では無いので整数である2と比較する演算子である'<'はサポートされないためタイプエラーになっているわけです。

該当の文の冗長さを削減し、ミスを修正した結果はこちらです。
n=int(input("素数かどうか知りたい数を入力してください。\n知りたい数＞＞"))

ただし、上記だけでは整数に変換できるもの以外の文字(数値の範囲ではあっても小数点のピリオドとか)が入力された場合、例外が発生してエラー終了します。
それは処理を継続するかどうかを尋ねる2つ目のinput()文でも同じです。
ちなみにそうした状況を質問に提示された間違ったinput()文とif n==str:以後の判定で対処しようと考えたのでしょうが、それも間違っています。
これは対処方法とは別の余談ですが、ある変数の型が何であるかは、型名の文字列と直接比較することは出来ません。
if n==str:は間違いで、type()を使います。
仕様説明はイマイチ分からないのでこちらの記事などを参考にしてください。
Pythonで型を取得・判定するtype関数, isinstance関数
if n==str:で想定したであろう処理と等価な形であるなら、if type(n) is str:となるでしょう。
そしてそのif文だけをそのように変更しても、元の質問ではnはtupleなので該当せずelif n<2:の判定が行われて例外が発生してエラー終了します。

なるべく簡単な変更で済ますには、通常行われる処理と異常発生時の処理を例外処理であるtry: ... except: ...で切り分けて囲んでおけば良いでしょう。仕様説明はこちら 8. エラーと例外
例えば以下のようになります。(行末に #### があるのが追加・変更した箇所)
k=1
while k==1:
    happen=0
    i=2
    try: ####
      n=int(input("素数かどうか知りたい数を入力してください。\n知りたい数＞＞")) ####
      if n<2: ####
        print(n,"は素数ではありません。")
      elif n>=2:
        if n%2==0 or n%3==0 or n%5==0 or n%7==0:
          print(n,"は素数ではありません。")
        else:
          while i<n**0.5:
            total=n%i
            i=i+1
            if total==0:
              happen=happen+1
          if happen>0:
            print(n,"は素数ではありません。")
          elif happen==0:
            print(n,"は素数です。")
    except: ####
      print("それは整数ではありません。") ####
    
    try: ####
      k=int(input("続けて素数を探しますか。Yes=1,No=0\nY/N>>")) ####
      if k==0:
        break
      else: ####
        k=1
    except: ####
      pass ####

print()

ただし、11未満の整数を入力するとすべて 'x は素数ではありません。' と表示された(x は入力値)ので素数判定処理の何処かが間違っています。
素数

最小の素数は 2 である。素数は無数に存在する。したがって、素数からなる無限数列が得られる。
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97,…

正しい処理についてはこんな記事とか、他にも検索して見つかる記事が色々とあるので参考にしてみてください。
Pythonで素数判定を行う方法を初心者向けに実例6選で解説
Pythonで素数判定を徹底解説！試し割り法からエラトステネスの篩まで完全ガイド

if type(n) is str: では, NoneやEllipsisのように単一のインスタンスであれば問題ないけど, strが単一とはドキュメントには書いてないように思います。(たまに判定にミスが入り込むかも) ヌルオブジェクト

余談として書いたので、その辺は深く考えていませんでしたね。なので変更例には組み込んでいません。

わざわざ間違いを示す必要はないので if type(n) == str: では

いや、リンクで紹介した記事に書いてあった内容と記述を合わせて、それをif文に適用したからですけど。紹介記事の方はprint()文のパラメータに指定していた形ですね。

「エラーで返すのではなく、例外処理として無視してほしい」
無理に例外処理を使わず入力された文字列が数字かチェックすれば良いのではないですか？
例えば 文字列の isdigit メソッドを使用する方法があります。
数字であれば、int関数 で 数値（int 型）に変換できます。
（int関数では全角の数字も変換してくれるようです。）
質問のプログラムを書き換えてみました。
(1) print関数に渡す文字列は「フォーマット済み文字列リテラル」というものを使っています。
f""の形ですが、変数又は式を{}で囲むと変数の値や式の結果に置き換えてくれるので便利です。
文字の { }は２つ重ねます。 {{ }}
(2) input の結果を格納する s, k は文字列にしました。
(3) 改行の前に空白と\を記述すると行の継続ができます。
(4) happen = happen + 1 は happen += 1 としました
k = "1"
while k == "1":
    happen = 0
    i = 2
    s = input("素数かどうか知りたい数を入力してください。\n知りたい数＞＞")
    if not s.isdigit():
        print("それは数字ではありません。")
    else:
        n = int(s)
        if n < 2:
            print(f"{n}は素数ではありません。")
        else:
            if n % 2 == 0 or \
               n % 3 == 0 or \
               n % 5 == 0 or \
               n % 7 == 0:
                print(f"{n}は素数ではありません。")
            else:
                while i < n**0.5:
                    total = n % i
                    i = i + 1
                    if total == 0:
                        happen += 1
                if happen > 0:
                     print(f"{n}は素数ではありません。")
                elif happen == 0:
                     print(f"{n}は素数です。")
    k = input("続けて素数を探しますか。Yes=1,No=0\nY/N>>")
    if k == "0":
        break
    else:
      k = "1"
print()

ご参考になれば幸いです。

皆様、お忙しい中ご意見ありがとうございました。今回の問題について、コードの改善能力不足や勉強不足などにより発生してしまったようです。"try.......except"を使った構文、s.isdigit()を使った数値とそれ以外の判定のためにそもそもint 指定にしないでn を決定する、コードの冗長の改善、などなどのご意見をいただきました（今回はtry.....except を利用してみました）。問題は解決し、また新しい課題を手に入れられる段階までになりました。支援してくださり、有難うございました。


n が数字型以外だと'<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'というエラーが起きてしまうのですが、

数字型以外だとエラーが出る、というなら、数字型に変換すればいいだけです。
その変換方法はぐぐればたいてい出てきます。
また、何を判断するのか、をあなたの中ではっきりさせましょう
inputで得られる結果は文字列です。
文字列としての判断（文字列が同じか、だとか何文字目に何の文字があるか、など）ならそのままで判断すればいいし、これを数値としてみた場合を判断したいなら、文字列を数値に変換すればいい、ってことになります
